# Scroll modificar el scroll, como hacerlo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hice esto, lo que básicamente hace es ocultar el scroll, ¿hay otra manera de hacerlo?

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 188px;
}

.barra {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 208px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="barra">
    hola mundo <br/> 
    hola como estas <br/> 
    hola america <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/> 
    hola america <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tienes la etiqueta de [tag:javascript], ¿quieres una solución basada en HTML+CSS (lo que tienes ahora) o estás abierto a usar código JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sólo lo que tienes no es suficiente. Estás poniendo un valor de 20 pixels para el scroll, pero no estás poniendo restricciones al texto en la izquierda, lo que puede hacer que en algunos casos el texto se corte y no se vea bien.

Por ejemplo, el texto se ve cortado al menos en Chrome 57:

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 188px;
}

.barra {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 208px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="barra">
    A veces se corta el texto y sto podría ser un problemilla que no quieres tener.<br/> 
    <br/>
    Hola<br/>
    Mundo<br/>
    Adiós<br/>
    Mundo<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Te recomendaría que hicieses algunos cambios en tu código para evitar esto y que se vea mejor:

- Mueve el borde del hijo al padre, para que no se vea un borde cortado.
- Añádele un `padding-right` al hijo del mismo tamaño de la caja ocultada (en este caso 208-188 = 20px).
- Haz que el `padding` del hijo cuente como parte del ancho (usando `box-sizing:border-box`).
- Opcionalmente, fuerza que el scroll se muestre siempre (con `overflow-y:scroll`).
- Opcionalmente, oculta más de 20 pixels. Puede que los usuarios hayan personalizado su navegador para que los scrollers sean más grandes.

Con esos cambios, el código se vería así:

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 188px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.barra {
  height: 80px;
  overflow:auto;
  width: 208px;
  border:0;
  padding-right:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="barra">
    A veces se corta el texto y sto podría ser un problemilla que no quieres tener.<br/>  
    <br/>
    Hola<br/>
    Mundo<br/>
    Adiós<br/>
    Mundo<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrias intentar algo como esto:

```css
.contenedor {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:188px;
}

.barra {
    width:208px;
    height:80px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor"> 
  <div class="barra">
    hola mundo <br/>
    hola como estas <br/>
    hola america <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    hola america <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que he realizado aca es quitar la propiedad que aplicaste de forma general a los `<div>`:

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 188px;
}
```

Y se separa en dos elementos, bien ya tenias `.barra`, asi que he separado el otro `div`, con el nombre, "contenedor".

```
.contenedor {
   overflow:hidden;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

Y posteriormente, se le aplico las propiedades al `div` de contenedor.

PD: He realizado las pruebas en Chrome y en Firefox. No aparece la barra de desplazamiento.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar a ocultar la barra con el div contenedor, para ello usa las propiedades `margin-right` y `padding-bottom` :

```css
.container {
  width : 100%;
  overflow : hidden;
  height : 200px;
}

.scroll {
  overflow : scroll;
  max-height : 200px;
  margin-right : -15px;
  padding-bottom : 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll">
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkjmbmnbmnbmnbmnbmnbmnbmnbmnbmnbmnbmnbmnbmnbmsadadasdsadsadsadsa<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
    ñkjdlkdjldkj<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Si tienes la alternativa de utilizar una librería adicional, te recomiendo usar la siguiente :

[Perfect Scroll Bar](https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/)

la cual oculta el scrollbar y lo muestra solo al hacer hover.

Answer (score 2):

Usando CSS puedes esconder la scrollbar en Webkit, Gecko y MS IE/Edge. No estoy seguro de Edge, pero supongo se puede de igual forma que con IE.

```css
body {
  background-color: turquoise;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 25px;
}

div {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

html {
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Este método tiene algunas falencias, como que en Firefox no se puede hacer scroll con el mousewheel (solo con las flechas de navegación). Otra alternativa es hacerlo mediante JavaScript.

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

(() => {
  const offsetW = wrapper.offsetWidth;
  const offsetH = wrapper.offsetHeight;
  const clientW = wrapper.clientWidth;
  const clientH = wrapper.clientHeight;
  const scrollW = offsetW - clientW;
  const scrollH = offsetH - clientH;
  const docW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
  const docH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  
  const {
    top, right,
    left, bottom
  } = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();

  const hasScroll = {
    horiz: scrollH > 0,
    vert: scrollW > 0,
  };
  
  const createHider = orientation => {
    const hider = document.createElement('div');
    hider.classList.add('hider');
    
    if (orientation === 'horizontal') {
      hider.style.height = scrollH + 'px';
      hider.style.width = clientW + 'px';
      hider.style.bottom = (docH - (bottom + top)) + 'px';
      hider.style.left = left + 'px';
    }
    
    if (orientation === 'vertical') {
      hider.style.top = top + 'px';
      hider.style.right = (docW - right) + 'px';
      hider.style.height = clientH + 'px';
      hider.style.width = scrollW + 'px';
    }
    
    return hider;
  };

  if (hasScroll.horiz) {
    wrapper.appendChild(createHider('horizontal'));
  }

  if (hasScroll.vert) {
    wrapper.appendChild(createHider('vertical'));
  }
})();
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: turquoise;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 80%;
}

.child {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 550px;
}

.hider {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

El segundo enfoque es usado también para crear scrollbars personalizadas que sean cross-browser, ya que haciéndolo mediante `::-webkit-scrollbar` no obtienes soporta para otros navegadores que no sean basados en webkit/blink.